# zsh: killed code . command on MacOs M1 chip monterey machine

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vim, zsh

So, I was trying to open **vscode** from terminal writing the following:
`code .`
so, I got the following

```
/usr/local/bin/code: line 6: python: command not found
/usr/local/bin/code: line 10: ./MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory
```

so, I tried to edit this file using vim `sudo vim /usr/local/bin/code` and changed the `python` to `python3` and saved using `:wq!`

it didn't edit it as it's a read-only file, however, I open it as a root user who has a write-permission, giving me an error that

`E166: Can't open linked file for writing`,

and now when I try to do `code .` in the terminal it gives me

`zsh: killed     code .`

and it's kinda stuck at this phase, now how can I open vscode from the terminal given that scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`code` is a **read-only** file that already had been added to $PATH. It originally located in `/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/` given that you are on a Mac machine.

to fix

`/usr/local/bin/code: line 6: python: command not found`

you would need to change `python` to `python3` using any editor giving `code` file the right permissions so you can edit it.

so,

1. `sudo chmod 774 code` now you have permission to edit it.
2. change `python` to `python3` and save the file.
3. restart the terminal.

and now, it should work fine, as it did for me.

Answer (score -1):

1. Use shortcut keys "CTRL+SHIFT+P" in your vscode.
2. Choose command "Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH"

[image]

3. Restart the terminal for the new value to take effect. You'll be able to type 'code .' in any folder to start editing files in that folder.

You can refer to the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac) for more details.

Comment: well, I believe that it's not about appending vscode to the $PATH, cause it was already there. the thing is I had to change ```python``` to ```python3``` as the first error trying to tell me. I had a problem that **vim** won't let me overwrite it even when I have root permission. so I had to give it full permissions using ```sudo chmod 777 code```  so I can overwrite it. now, I've changed ```python``` to ```python3``` and it's working. thankyou for your answer.